# Smooth curved line between 3 points in plot

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I have 3 data points on the x axis and 3 on the y axis:

```
x = [1,3,5]
y=[0,5,0]
```

I would like a curved line that starts at (1,0), goes to the highest point at (3,5) and then finishes at (5,0)

I think I need to use interpolation, but unsure how. If I use spline from scipy like this:

```
import bokeh.plotting as bk
from scipy.interpolate import spline
p = bk.figure()
xvals=np.linspace(1, 5, 10)
y_smooth = spline(x,y,xvals)
p.line(xvals, y_smooth)

bk.show(p)
```

I get the highest point before (3,5) and it looks unbalanced:
[image]

Comment: Do you have to use bokeh?

Comment: @pylang yes, but I have to use bokeh

Comment: You can always just fit it with a polynomial of degree 2.

Comment: Doing exactly what you do but plotting it with matplotlib (can't get bokeh to work because p is undefined) get's me a perfectly symmetric graph.

Comment: @Nathan hmm, thanks. so it might be related to bokeh. I updated with the value of p, but yeah it might be just bokeh

Comment: @Nathan: That's odd, because that is **not** what I see. I get an asymmetrical graph, just as the OP. This has to do with how `spline`works, and not the bokeh/matplotlib.

Comment: @JohanL I did it again and now I also get an assymetric plot... Sorry about that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is due to that `spline` with no extra argument is of order 3. That means that you do not have points/equations enough to get a spline curve (which manifests itself as a warning of an ill-conditioned matrix). You need to apply a spline of lower order, such as a cubic spline, which is of order 2:

```
import bokeh.plotting as bk
from scipy.interpolate import spline
p = bk.figure()
xvals=np.linspace(1, 5, 10)
y_smooth = spline(x,y,xvals, order=2) # This fixes your immediate problem
p.line(xvals, y_smooth)

bk.show(p)
```

In addition, `spline` is deprecated in SciPy, so you should preferably not use it, even if it is possible. A better solution is to use the `CubicSpline` class:

```
import bokeh.plotting as bk
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline
p = bk.figure()
xvals=np.linspace(1, 5, 10)
spl = CubicSpline(x, y) # First generate spline function
y_smooth = spl(xvals) # then evalute for your interpolated points
p.line(xvals, y_smooth)

bk.show(p)
```

Just to show the difference (using pyplot):

[image]

As can be seen, the `CubicSpline` is identical to the `spline` of `order=2`

Answer (score 4):

use `pchip_interpolate()`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

x = [1,3,5]
y=[0,5,0]

x2 = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 100)
y2 = interpolate.pchip_interpolate(x, y, x2)
pl.plot(x2, y2)
pl.plot(x, y, "o")
```

the result:

[image]

Comment: for my actual purpose the pchip provides the best results

Answer (score 2):

You can use quadratic interpolation. This is possible by making use of `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import numpy as np



x = [1, 3, 5]
y = [0, 5, 0]

f = interp1d(x, y, kind='quadratic')

x_interpol = np.linspace(1, 5, 1000)
y_interpol = f(x_interpol)

plt.plot(x_interpol, y_interpol)
plt.show()
```

Check the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d) for more details.